# Applying the polynomial remainder theorem - does this logic hold for working out factors?

Tags: polynomials

Let's say I have some function of $x$ and an unknown integer $d$, given by

$f(x) = x^2 + d^2 + dx$

and I want to see if it's divisible by something like $x-d$;as I understand it, we could apply the polynomial remainder theorem and find the remainder, $r = f(d) = 3d^2$.  Now, I believe I can then argue that this is zero if $d=0$, which is obviously true. But I also can see that this isn't sufficient alone; for example, if $x-d=1$, then $x-d$ will divide always.

My question is thus, can I say that $x-d$ is a factor of $f(x)$ only when EITHER $d=0$ or $x-d=1$, or are there another situations I'm missing?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say that $x - d = 1$; you're considering this function as $x$ ranges over all of its possible values, and $d$ is unknown but *fixed*.

Comment: What Qiaochu Yuan commented.  However, I upvoted your query, for your good presentation and work, and for stretching your intuition by questioning everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we speak about division over polynomials, it means $p(x)|q(x)$ for any $x$, as @QiaochuYuan said. If you consider $x-d=1$, it means $x$ is no more free variable and is $x=d+1$, so $f(x)=f(d+1)$, and therefore both become constants, and you are speak about division over constant integers! Notice in polynomials, there is no necessity to have integer coefficients for speaking about division.